# Swift ambiguous use of UUID with CoreBluetooth and HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, uuid, core-bluetooth, healthkit

I am creating an iOS Swift app that needs to have access to CoreBluetooth in order to interact with a heart rate monitor. This works OK.

I also want to save the heart rate using HealthKit, however when I import HealthKit into the application (even in a separate file) I get the following error;

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0YWr.png]

This is in relation to service.UUID. Whilst here it is only printing the line, service.UUID is used in other locations and gives the same error. However without HealthKit import, service.UUID works fine.

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
    for service in peripheral.services{
        NSLog("Discovered service: \(service.UUID)")
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service as CBService)
    }
}
```

I have used both HealthKit, and CoreBluetooth separately, and it works OK but combining the two gives the ambiguity error. Is there a way to explicitly tell which it should use?

Thanks,

Comment: Try this `for service in peripheral.services as [CBService]{}`

Comment: @MidhunMP Perfect! That solved the issue, Thanks. Do you want to add it as a Q and I shall mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is both CBService and HealthKit have UUID property. When you call `peripheral.services` it returns a `AnyObject` array. So fixing this issue typecast that to `CBService`.

```
for service in peripheral.services as [CBService]
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HealthKit assigns a UUID to the object when you create it. If you want to add your own unique ID, add it to the object’s metadata using the HKMetadataKeyExternalUUID key.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/HKObject/UUID

Comment: Its not that I want to assign a uniqueID to the HealthKit, its that when I import HealthKit the code doesn't know if it should use the CoreBluetooth UUID or the HealthKit UUID.

Comment: You have to add the CoreBluetooth's UUID to the object's metadata.